# Zero(0) value store in CodeIgniter(CI) while inserting data ?

Tags: php

I have this code in my model file,

```
function add_records($data){
    $this->db->insert('data', $data);
    return;
}
```

and in controller file

```
function create(){
    $data = array(
        'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
        'content' => $this->input->post('content')
        );

    // $this->load->model('site_model'); # site_model is autoload
    $this->site_model->add_records($data);
    $this->index();
}
```

And my value store in database is zero(0) for both input title and content. Do you have any idea what is happening ?

Comment: is the table fields `char` or `varchar` ?

Comment: is your table actually called data?